# Word find, search for all numbers, exclude year

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to do a simple find in a Word document for all instances of numbers (Im checking data). I can do this in find using ^#

However, how do I exclude in the search '2019'.

Thanks, Rogerbij

Comment: I tried to use build-in Find and Replace tool to do this. However, i failed to work it out. We need to use macros maybe.

Comment: One way to work around using macros is to change all instances of 2019 to text (e.g. TwentyNineteen) using Find and Replace, run the search and get only numbers other than 2019, then when the task is complete, change the text back to 2019.

Comment: Thanks KnotWrite, thats the workaround idea I went with... of course the actual idea is to be able to click through data ignoring other years too, like 2018, 2020... Its a bit cumbersome but works. Cheers